# Check wether a specific place in NSArray is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, null, nsarray

I'm trying to check if a place in my array is nil like so:

```
if (resultArray[1] == nil) {
    NSLog(@"...");
}
```

But it always crashes with the message:
`[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'`

How can I fix this, or is there any other way to check it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (resultArray[1] == nil) {
    NSLog(@"..."); // <-- will NEVER be called
}
```

NSArray can't hold nils.

try index `0`, as your array just holds one element, and that's index ist `0`, the last possible index of an array is `[array count] - 1`. Or as range of all indices: `0..[array count] - 1`

```
if([resultArray count] > 1){
    // holds at least 2 objects, valid indices: `0..[array count] - 1`
} else ([resultArray count]){
    // holds exactly 1 object, valid indices: `0..0`
} else {
   // empty, no valid index
}
```

Comment: if you gave us more context, we'd might be able to offer better code.

Comment: What I'm trying to do fetch Core Data results as an array. My array isn't meant to hold one element but many, I just need the first 2: 0 and 1. But I need to check if one of them is empty(or both) and act accordingly

Comment: according to the error your array holds exactly one element.

Comment: and as I said: arrays cannot hold nil objects.

Comment: Well yes, in this case specifically. But anyways, how can I check wether that place is empty? If it has a value?

Comment: if it has a value, it is not empty. if it is empty, it is nil. and arrays don't hold nil. This is true for ANY NSArray, nothing special about this case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't have empty places in them. Every single slot in an array must contain an object. You use array.count to figure out how many objects the array contains. If array.count returns 0, the array is empty (or nil, which can be confusing, but that's another story.)

If array.count returns 3, then array[0], array[1] and array[2] **MUST** contain non-nil values. That's how NSArray objects work.

This is different from a C array, where an array of pointers CAN contain a null value.